# JTextArea forces the parent JScrollPane to scroll down

Tags: java, swing, focus, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I have a panel inside a JScrollPane and I dynamically populate the panel with components as the data gets received from the service. The panel uses GridBagLayout (but that should be irrelevant). For each record that comes back from the service, I create several components dynamically and append them to the bottom of the panel. Everything works fine, but the problem is that JTextArea that gets created for each record forces the main JScrollPane to scroll down and show the last added JTextArea, as shown here:

[image: scroll pane forced down]

I tried to disable everything I could think of to dumb down the JTextArea, but still doesn't help

```
JTextArea descriptionArea = new JTextArea(project.getDescription().replace("<br>", "\n"));
descriptionArea.setEditable(false);
descriptionArea.setFont(thumbnailLabel.getFont());
descriptionArea.setLineWrap(true);
descriptionArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);    
descriptionArea.setFocusable(false);
descriptionArea.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);    
DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) descriptionArea.getCaret();
caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.NEVER_UPDATE);
```

How can I prevent it from moving the scrollbar? I tried replacing JTextArea with JLabel and that works, but I can't get the JLabel to word wrap the text as good. Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
Point p = srcollPane.getViewport().getViewPostition();
// add the components to the panel in the viewport of the scrollpane
scrollpane.getViewport().setViewPosition( p );
```

Now the scrollpane should be reset to its original position before you added the components.

Comment: thank you. I have experimented with that solution before and it didn't work. I just managed to get it to work when doing the setViewPosition wrapped inside the SwingUtilities.invokeLater() call.